# getting not defined error even though declared variable as declare var xyz in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, chat

```
declare
var WhWidgetSendButton;

ngOnInit() {
  var options = {
    facebook: "xxxx", // Facebook page ID
    whatsapp: "xxx", // WhatsApp number
    call_to_action: "Message us", // Call to action
    button_color: "#008000", // Color of button
    position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
    order: "whatsapp,facebook", // Order of buttons
  };
  var proto = document.location.protocol;
  var host = "whatshelp.io";
  var url = proto + "//static." + host;
  let s = document.createElement('script');
  s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.async = true;
  s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';

  s.onload = () => {
    WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options);
  };
  let x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are declaring the variable `WhWidgetSendButton`, but you never set it.

In essence, `WhWidgetSendButton = undefined`, and then you are attempting to call `.init(host, proto, options)` on an undefined variable.

Before you call `init` you need to set `WhWidgetSendButton` to something like `WhWidgetSendButton = new WhWidgetSendButton()`.

Comment: the error is " WhWidgetSendButton  not defined " ,unlike undefined variable

Comment: WhWidgetSendButton never gets set anywhere in your code -- it looks like a library you are trying to utilize maybe, but `var WhWidgetSendButton;` sets that to undefined.  

Think about it this way;

`var x;`
`x.doSomething()` 

would never work because `x` was never instantiated (or defined).

this would work though:
```var x = new SomeClass();
x.doSomething()```

because `x` was defined.